# How to dynamic layout inflator within a loop

Tags: android, loops, android-linearlayout

**I want inflate dynamic LinearLayout with one TextView within loop. This is for page with info. I have tried with this code:**

**The xml of the parent page is:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="em.example.InfoActivity">


    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/infolayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**The xml of the child page is:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#55934d"
    android:padding="5dp"> 

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TextAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT ADDRESS:"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

**And this is main activity:**

```
public void showInfo(){
    LayoutInflater layoutInfralte=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.infolayout);
    List views=new ArrayList();

    Iterator<latlng>ite=NavigationContext.getInstance().getArray().iterator();
    latlng temp;
    while(ite.hasNext()){
        temp=ite.next();
        View view=layoutInfralte.inflate(R.layout.infoitem, null);
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextAddress);
        tv.setText(temp.address);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        views.add(view);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<views.size(); i++)
        linearLayout.addView((View) views.get(i));
}
```

**Error:**

```
08-05 17:40:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(3163): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 17:40:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(3163): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{em.example/em.example.InfoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 17:40:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-05 17:40:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-05 17:40:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
```

Comment: replace findViewById with view.findViewById

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem in getting refrence to the textView

```
public void showInfo(){
LayoutInflater layoutInfralte=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.infolayout);
List views=new ArrayList();

Iterator<latlng>ite=NavigationContext.getInstance().getArray().iterator();
latlng temp;
while(ite.hasNext()){
    temp=ite.next();
    View view=layoutInfralte.inflate(R.layout.infoitem, null);
    // Edit
    TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextAddress);
    tv.setText(temp.address);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    views.add(view);
}
for(int i = 0; i<views.size(); i++)
    linearLayout.addView((View) views.get(i));
  }
```